# Converting complex native query to JPQL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Can someone help me with converting this native query to JPQL.. because I need the response as myResponse DTO, but native query can only give List<Object[]>

```
"select t.*, (select count(*) from test.tag_association ta 
where t.id=ta.tag_id and ta.entity_type='USERS') as tagged_users,
    (select count(*) from test.tag_association ta 
     where t.id=ta.tag_id and ta.entity_type='BUNDLES') as tagged_bundles from test.tag t 
     where t.is_active=1 order by t.updated_timestamp desc"
```

Comment: i suggest you to check out spring data jpa projections, it allows you to get specific fields from db by using interfaces, you can check examples from this blog post https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: @IsaToltar Actually I tried the constructor based projection from one of the posts from the same blog.. (https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions) It seems we need to make the @Query() with JPQL only to get it on my response DTO class.. after trying several times to rewrite the native query to JPQL I posted here for help!